# DragSource - InvalidDnDOperationException on starting DragAction

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

my application contains a few JPanels that sould be moved by DnD. I have implemented all listeners and handlers, everything seems to be right. When dragging one panel with the mouse my DragGestureListener recognizes that and wants to start a new DragAction:

```
    @Override
    public void dragGestureRecognized(DragGestureEvent dge) {

        // When the drag begins, we need to grab a reference to the
        // parent container so we can return it if the drop
        // is rejected
        Container parent = getPanel().getParent();

        setParent(parent);

        // Remove the panel from the parent.  If we don't do this, it
        // can cause serialization issues.  We could over come this
        // by allowing the drop target to remove the component, but that's
        // an argument for another day
        parent.remove(getPanel());

        // Update the display
        parent.invalidate();
        parent.repaint();

        // Create our transferable wrapper
        TicketTransferable transferable = new TicketTransferable(getPanel());

        // Start the "drag" process...

        dge.startDrag(null, transferable);

    }
```

But then following exception occurs:

```
exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.dnd.InvalidDnDOperationException: 
     Cannot find top-level for the drag source component
at sun.awt.X11.XDragSourceContextPeer.startDrag(XDragSourceContextPeer.java:126)
at sun.awt.dnd.SunDragSourceContextPeer.startDrag(SunDragSourceContextPeer.java:134)
```

I checked XDragSourceContextPeer and found out that the component that triggers the DragAction (In my case the JPanel to move itself) must be of type "Window" to start the drag properly. The Point is that my JPanel just isnt a window and the mentioned Exception is thrown back.

What am I doing wrong?

P.S.: All "moveable" panels are in different cells of an JTable.

Comment: _must be of type "Window"_ answers the question _What am I doing wrong?_ That said, smelly parts a) why a panel as data in a table? b) why not use the standard swing/table dragging (aka: a custom TransferHandler) Anyway, most probably no help possible without a SSCCE demonstrating the problem

Comment: I solved it. I forgot to set table.setDragEnabled(true) and         table.setDropMode(DropMode.INSERT); Thx kleopatra for you help :-)

Comment: glad you solved it :-)

Comment: @Randbedingung don't leave a solved question unanswered! If you find a solution, post it as an answer and accept it :3